# running user input through python script and returning output on django site

Tags: python, django

new python/django user here. i'm trying to set up a webpage that takes user input (e.g., an address) into a form, then passes it through a python script (in a separate.py file) before returning an output to the same webpage (e.g., the nearest traffic light).

how would i go about making the connection between my views.py file and my script.py file in django?

***simplified code:***
**views.py file**
input = form.cleaned_data.get('enter_address')

**script.py file**
print(input)

Comment: Can you import the function that script.py runs and run it directly in you view?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to run python script

```
os.system("example.py 1")
```

or

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("example.py 1", shell=True)
```